# How to get a single instance for an associated read-only entity with JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, orm

I have this two entities:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Cacheable
@Cache(region = "dosefrequency", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class DoseFrequency{
   .....
} 

@Entity
public class PrescriptionDrug {

     .....
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="doseFrequency")   
    public DoseFrequency getDoseFrequency() {
        return doseFrequency;
     }

}
```

DoseFrequency is a read only entity, and PrescriptionDrug has associated one DoseFreqyency. I want to achive that each time I load one or many PrescriptionDrug the instances of DoseFrequency don't be repeated.

I know that the DoseFrequency instances will be cached in the first level cache of hibernate, but the load is done in several sessions (it is a web app). I used the second level cache, but that cache doesn't store instances only serializes the entity.

I get this behaivor working using Tuplizer in DoseFrequency, but I don't know if there is any other way to achive this.

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Cacheable
@Cache(region = "dosefrequency", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Tuplizer(impl=DoseFrequencyTuplizer.class)
public class DoseFrequency {
   ....
}


public class DoseFrequencyTuplizer extends PojoEntityTuplizer {

    public DoseFrequencyTuplizer(EntityMetamodel entityMetamodel, PersistentClass mappedEntity) {
        super(entityMetamodel, mappedEntity);
    }

    @Override
    protected Instantiator buildInstantiator(EntityMetamodel entityMetamodel, PersistentClass persistentClass) {
        return new DoseFrequencyInstantiator(DoseFrequency.class.getName(),entityMetamodel,persistentClass,null);
    }

    }


public class DoseFrequencyInstantiator implements Instantiator {

    private final Class targetClass;
    protected PojoEntityInstantiator pojoEntityInstantiator;

    public DoseFrequencyInstantiator(String targetClassName, EntityMetamodel entityMetamodel,
            PersistentClass persistentClass, ReflectionOptimizer.InstantiationOptimizer optimizer) {
        try {
            this.targetClass = Class.forName(targetClassName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new HibernateException(e);
        }

        pojoEntityInstantiator = new PojoEntityInstantiator(entityMetamodel, persistentClass, optimizer);

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiate(Serializable id) {
        DoseFrequency df = MedereEMRCache.instance.findDoseFrequencyByID(Long.valueOf(id.toString()));
        if (df == null) {
            return pojoEntityInstantiator.instantiate(id);
        }
        return df;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiate() {
        return instantiate(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInstance(Object object) {
        try {
            return targetClass.isInstance(object);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new HibernateException("could not get handle to entity as interface : " + t);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm aware that the instances will be shared among all the threads of the application, but they are treated as read only, so they should not be modified.

Is this approach right?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a `LoadEventListener` to always serve the same instance. Nevertheless, this functionality is not needed since the entity is immutable, so, even if you have multiple copies of it, it will still be immutable.

More, even if you implement a Singleton pattern, it will only be enforced per JVM, so I don't see why you'd want to implement this request.

Entities are meant to treated as singletons per `EntityManager` only.

Comment: Thank you Vlad for the answer. In the sampler of VisualVM the instances of the inmutable objects always rise each time that I load them (Of course the GC cleans them). I want to avoid to implement like a singleton for those entities. I will try with the LoadEventListener, thank you again